# Hosting raw HTML pages in a Pelican static website

Tags: python, html, pelican

Is there a way in Pelican (Python) static site generator to pass in just a raw HTML page only? At the moment I am trying to place a google-site-verification HTML file to be permanent hosted in the root directory. I have run into this issue a few other times, unrelated to the google site verification.

In an ideal world I would place the HTML file in the `content` directory, like an `rst` or an `md` file, and then it is picked up and dropped into the `output` directory. This is obviously not working, hence why I am here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest way to include arbitrary files in the output is with [`EXTRA_PATH_METADATA`](http://docs.getpelican.com/en/3.6.3/settings.html#path-metadata) and `STATIC_PATHS`. For example, from [my blog's config](https://github.com/textbook/textbook.github.io-source/blob/c3357e08fb611349967bf248785d737abd795573/pelicanconf.py#L58):

```
STATIC_PATHS = [
    'images',
    'extra',
]
EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {
    'extra/custom.css': {'path': 'custom.css'},
    'extra/robots.txt': {'path': 'robots.txt'},
    'extra/favicon.ico': {'path': 'favicon.ico'},
    'extra/CNAME': {'path': 'CNAME'},
    'extra/LICENSE': {'path': 'LICENSE'},
    'extra/README': {'path': 'README'},
}
```

This takes the specified files from `/content/extra` and puts them in the root of `/output`.

As you have an HTML file in your extras, you will also need to include your static directory in `ARTICLE_EXCLUDES` to prevent Pelican from trying to process the file.

Comment: This almost works, I placed my html file in the static directory, but it failed, as it tried to render the html file, which is what I don't want.  It worked once I used ARTICLE_EXCLUDES = ['static'] in my pelicanconf.py, which ignores that directory for rendering, which is pretty much what I place in directory in general.

Comment: @DouglasKastle good point, added; I don't have any HTML files there, so there was nothing for Pelican to *try* to process.

Comment: Cool thanks for the correction.  I think this is the answer, just waiting for magic ...

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44209338/2327328) helped me, but this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44209165/hosting-raw-html-pages-in-a-pelican-static-website#comment75431936_44209338) wasn't necessary IF you want the static HTML rendered

Here's snippet from `pelicanconf.py` that is working for me, which adds a static site based on the html file located at `content/html/page_name.html` with this path `http://localhost/page_name.html`

```
STATIC_PATHS = [
    'images',
    'extra',
    'html',
]
EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {
    'extra/custom.css': {'path': 'custom.css'},
    'extra/robots.txt': {'path': 'robots.txt'},
    'extra/favicon.ico': {'path': 'favicon.ico'},
    'extra/CNAME': {'path': 'CNAME'},
    'extra/LICENSE': {'path': 'LICENSE'},
    'extra/README': {'path': 'README'},
    'html/page_name.html' : {'path' : 'page_name.html'}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a couple solutions to these issues. First, for the site verification. You can either just manually add the verification file when you push the generated content out, or add a `<meta>` tag to the site template. You can read more about your options here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?hl=en

As for embedding HTML into a pelican site, you can use reStructuredText (.rst) instead of Markdown (.md) and then you can import the html. Explanation [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/4o5sx7/embedding_html_into_a_pelican_site/) on reddit.